# Reformatting Problem

Tags: formatting

I have a problem formatting my laptop. I install Windows XP Pro and i pass many steps but when it was on copying the files it hang on 2%, 5% and 11% any of that number..whats the problem of this..pls help ASAP..Tanx

Answer (score 2):

There is probably a problem with either your installation CD or your Hard drive. I would bet on the hard drive though. Since you are re-installing... your probably had issues with your previous installation?

Is this a new hard drive? You should get your hands on a knoppix live cd and open the terminal and run these commands after connecting to the internet:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

... wait for it to update

```
sudo apt-get install smartmontools
```

... follow the prompts to install it.

```
sudo smartctl -a /dev/hda
```

... if that doesnt work... try

```
sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda
```

This should give you a health status report on your hard drive. You can paste the report on here if you need help interpreting it.

Comment: tanx james..i think my hard drive is the problem because the technician says that when i insert cd in my hard drive it will hang up my laptop..so i think i will buy a usb hard drive..so whats your idea?

Comment: I don't think a usb hard drive will help. Your laptop has an internal hard drive that should be relatively easy to replace with a new one. Once you replace the internal hard drive, your windows installation should work. I would recommend following the steps I explained in the solution to make sure it is the hard drive.

Please look up "hard drive" on wikipedia or google or something. You can't put a cd in your hard drive. A hard drive is a very specific part of your laptop.